# How to get access to previous version's textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a resource pack using 12w34a leather armor. I already have the model texture, the actual armor texture, but I'm now looking for the item texture. What I mean for the item texture is the actual item itself, like if you were creating a leather helmet.

**EDIT:** To put more clarity of my request, I'm looking for 12w34a **[Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37PSR.jpg)** texture **NOT** **[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqkIv.jpg)** textures.

Comment: 1. Have you looked for the specific texture file online, for example in the wiki (also earlier versions of the wiki pages)? 2. Basically you'll have to start the old version, exit again, go into `.minecraft/versions`, unpack the .jar file and there it's somewhere in `assets`. At least that's the path for current versions, it might be different in old versions, but the procedure stays the same. 3. I'll write a proper answer later today.

Comment: I don't believe the item texture is available in the version jar file for those versions.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change the requirements after there's already an answer. That way you invalidate the answers. Now please read your question very carefully and make sure you're asking exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not changing anything, people seem not to understand the question and i've said what I'm not looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start the Minecraft version you want the textures of.
2. Exit the game. (optional)
3. Go to `%appdata%\.minecraft\versions`. (paste it into the path bar of Windows explorer like this)
4. Open the folder with the version name you want.
5. Open or unpack the `.jar` file with [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180419120603/https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1801-x64.exe)) or another archiving program.
6. There the textures are, but in a different structure in different versions. In 1.3.2 for example the texture you want is `gui/items.png` in the top left.

For downloading old snapshots, you can look in the wiki, for example the [12w34a wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/12w34a) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=12w34a&oldid=1191433)) links to [a download of the snapshot](http://assets.minecraft.net/12w34a/minecraft.jar) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180430105633/http://assets.minecraft.net/12w34a/minecraft.jar)).
For installation of old snapshots, read [this tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/How_to_install_a_snapshot#No_longer_available_in_the_Launcher) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Tutorials/How_to_install_a_snapshot&oldid=1186457#No_longer_available_in_the_Launcher)).

Comment: I'm looking for the item texture not the model texture

Comment: Ah, ok. But it should also be in one of these folders.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  You are right.  I downloaded the old snapshot and found the old textures the OP wants, based on what you commented.  Why not edit your answer with the updated path and a link to the old snapshot?

Comment: Ok, I've not changed the path, wrote how to find the old snapshots and gave a direct link (which you can also change up to get other versions in case the wiki goes down), linked a tutorial how to install old snapshots (even though that's not needed for this question) and archived it on web.archive.org just to be sure. I'm planning to do that with all links in my answers anyway, because StackExchange says that we shouldn't rely on external sites staying up. But I trust the web archive in that regard, they did it for as long as I live.

Comment: * not ----> now